# Why is modus ponens a valid form?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Why is modus ponens in prepositional logic considered a valid form?

I can think of an example where a true premise leads to a false conclusion:

```
If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him

The kid is wet in the winter

Conclusion: it was raining on him
```

Where, in fact,

```
The kid is wet in the winter

A passing car splashed water on him

Therefore, it is not the case that it was raining on him.
```

Comment: In the example you give, the conditional statement "If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him" is clearly **false** as demonstrated by the following statements you make. Modus ponens requires the implication in question to be **true**.

Comment: The result of an argument is true if its form is valid *and* its propositions are true. So here we have an argument with a valid form but false propositions, so the result being wrong doesn't mean that the form is invalid.

Comment: @lulu the purpose of the rule/form of modus ponens is to help deduce correctly,  but as my example shows it can lead also to a false conclusion even when the Premise (p) is true.

Comment: @Dasem But one of your premises is **not true** in the example you give. **Both** premises, the conditional statement and the hypothesis, have to hold in order to apply modus ponens: MP says that $Q$ is true whenever $P$ **and** $P\rightarrow Q$ are true.

Comment: Which of my premises is not true? The kid is wet is true.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. It's an honest question with an attempt. I see questions with absolutely no attempt get upvotes.

Comment: @Dasem See my original comment: your premise "If the kid is wet in the winter, then it was raining on him" (the "$P\rightarrow Q$"-part) is **false** in the situation you describe.

Comment: I think the issue is that you've missed that the conditional itself, as a required bit of knowledge, is itself a premise in your argument. If there's another way that the child could have gotten wet other than getting rained on, then the conditional in your argument is simply not true.

Comment: Ok i will think about it more, thanks to everyone.

Comment: @Dasem  I deleted my prior comment because I thought Noah Schweber's comment was more articulate.  In any case, M.P. requires that *both* $P\implies Q$ and $P$ be true.  In your case, $P\implies Q$ is false, so the logic does not apply.

Comment: @lulu understood, i will study this topic more.

Comment: To put a name to some of the points made above, it might help to read up on the distinction between *validity* and *soundness*. The example you gave is valid, but not sound.

Comment: @elliot i know the difference between them, it sounds if it is valid form and the Premises are true. therefore my example is valid as modus ponens form, the problem is if you assume the the conditional Premise is true and the antecedent (p) is true , you are forced to conclude the wrong conclusion q as true, and that is due to the truth table of the conditional operator even though the conclusion is wrong as my example shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe writing it formally helps. To deduce $q$ through modus ponens, we need:

$(p \implies q)  \wedge p$

i.e. the premise p *and the implication itself* must be true. Remember that $(p \implies q)$ is itself a proposition, either true or false. In your case, $p \implies q$ is NOT true, since a kid being wet does not imply that it has rained.

Modus ponens is the inference rule itself, but it doesn't tell you about whether the premises are true or not.

Comment: Thanks i will study your answer, but as far as i understand in general, p imply q or if p then q is a given definition (sorry i don't know hot to type in formal syntax and I'm typing from my phone)  or a Premise, and then we are given that p is true, according to my understanding we can't conclude q because there isn't additional information that attach p to q in order for us to conclude q, and that why i chose this example in the post, but i assume i missing something cause right now it isn't make sense to me, but as i said i will study your answer carefully, thanks.

Comment: Even though i excepted the answer my question still remains unanswered since they closed my other post/question on this subject, which mean they have created this wired situation by closing my other question and tagging it as duplicates even though they didn't even understand the question, but never mind.

Comment: But i will summarize my findings after dealing with it for a few days: modus ponens is a weak inference rule the only place it's solid is in math where it's represents there a neccessary connection any other places like in natural language as my example shows it can give a false conclusion and therefore it's invalid.

Comment: Your example is not a correct application of the inference rule called modus ponens. So no, it does not provide a counterexample and modus ponens is completely valid and is used extensively in both formal and natural language. Please study my answer and the comments below your question more carefully.

Comment: @ Lili i understand your answer, and i accepted it because at that time the truth table didn't show me a contradiction when i assumed q is false, and that happened because my logic book had a style of presenting the argument in 3 separated lines or columns and with your answer i manged to understand that the (and) operator was missing, after that the truth table worked.

Comment: But figuring that, is still doesn't solve the problem that my example shows when dealing with natural language, knowing the kid is wet in winter, doesn't mean it was raining on him, it's not a necessary connection like in math.

Comment: Here is another example: if the kid is smiling then he is happy, the kid is smiling therefore he is happy...wrong! the kid just faked the smile.

Comment: It's same as saying: if it have 4 legs then it's a dog, it have 4 legs, conclusion: it's a dog ...(No it is a cat) modus ponens is invalid inference rule.